# ¿Qué es "a la siga"?

Tags: modismos, expresiones, significado, chile

En la versión del cuento "Caperucita Roja" disponible en [esta web brasileña](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/pesquisa/PesquisaObraForm.do?select_action=&co_autor=2000) aparece la palabra *siga*, que no consigo entender ni encontrar en diccionarios:

> MORALEJA
>   Aquí vemos que la adolescencia,
>   en especial las señoritas,
>   bien hechas, amables y bonitas
>   no deben a cualquiera oír con complacencia,
>   y no resulta causa de extrañeza
>   ver que muchas del lobo son la presa.
>   Y digo el lobo, pues 
>   bajo su envoltura
>   no todos son de igual calaña: 
>   Los hay con no poca maña,
>   silenciosos, sin odio ni amargura,
>   que en secreto, pacientes, con dulzura
>   van **a la siga** de las damiselas
>   hasta las casas y en las callejuelas;
>   más, bien sabemos que los zalameros
>   entre todos los lobos ¡ay! son los más fieros

¿Qué quiere decir? ¿Equivale a "zaga"?, o ¿"van a la siga de las damiselas" es una construcción extraña de "van siguiendo a las damiselas"?

Comment: ¿Será parecido a "van en *busca* de algo"?

Answer (score 9):

[Encontré el libro](http://www.universitaria.cl/libro?isbn=956111934X) y parece ser editado por la Editorial Universitaria, que es chilena. Creo que este es un dato importante a destacar antes de mencionar la búsqueda.

Efectivamente, *siga* no aparece en el diccionario. Sin embargo, al buscar su significado en el DRAE nos redirecciona a *seguir* (pues *siga* es la 2.ª persona del singular en modo imperativo del verbo *seguir*).

Allí vemos al final del todo:

> [**siga**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XT8l8aE)
>   1. interj. Col. adelante.
>   2. interj. Col. En una comida, u. para indicar que se puede comenzar a comer.

Donde *Col.* indica Colombia. Por tanto, parecería que significa *adelante* en Colombia, por lo que el significado de la frase sería *van **adelante** de las damiselas*.

Sin embargo, leyendo la totalidad del texto vemos que efectivamente es raro y lo normal por el contexto sería lo contrario y que su significado real fuera *a la zaga*:

> [**a la zaga, a zaga, o en zaga**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cGzW0zs)
>   1. locs. advs. Atrás o detrás.

Y efectivamente, buscando un poco más di con un par de referencias:

En Wordreference bajo el título ["a la siga"](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-la-siga.1519620/?hl=es) dicen:

> *A la siga* de significa seguir a, ir detrás de. Este giro es muy común en el habla coloquial de Chile, sobre todo en las áreas rurales. Isabel Allende es Chilena y, por lo tanto, no es extraño el uso de este término en ella.

Y luego en Oxford Dictionaries:

> [Siga](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definicion/siga)
>   Chile Palabra que se usa en la expresión a la siga que significa 'tras de algo', en busca de algo.

Por tanto tu intuición casa con lo que parece ser, unido con el hecho de que la edición con la que trabajas sea chilena y, por tanto, propia del lugar donde tal expresión es utilizada.

<s>Ojalá algún amigo chileno del sitio (hola Rodrigo :P) nos pueda confirmar.</s> ¡Confirmado en la [respuesta de Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20444/1674), que es chileno!

Answer (score 6):

Si no haces la pregunta no me habría enterado de que es un chilenismo. Y me parece curioso que no esté en ningún diccionario, porque es una expresión que uno escucharía o diría un par de veces al mes acá en Chile. Googleando la encuentras en escritores chilenos más o menos desde 1900.

Bueno, de hecho lo que tú buscas no es "siga", sino "**a la siga de**", y ya te dijeron fedorqui y aparente001 lo que significa. Para detallar un poco, agrego que los chilenos lo usamos como locución preposicional, con el significado de "**tras**", abarcando más o menos lo que dirías con verbos como "buscar", "perseguir" o "acosar". En este caso, *los lobos acosan a las señoritas*.

Se usa acompañando a los verbos "ir", "estar", "venir" y sobre todo "andar". *Andar a la siga de...* significa "estar persiguiendo (a)..."

Ejemplos:

> Los jinetes van a la siga del ganado.
>
> Ando a la siga de ejemplares de "La Pequeña Lulú" anteriores a 1950.
>
> El sinvergüenza Ramírez anda a la siga de la secretaria nueva.

También usamos locuciones adverbiales, reemplazando el término del complemento por un pronombre de esta forma:

> La secretaria anda *a mi siga*. (La secre me está coqueteando).
>
> Doctor, la señora Pérez anda *a su siga* desde ayer. (La señora lo está buscando desde ayer).

Pero a pesar de esto, la palabra "siga" no es un sustantivo aislable. No tenemos "las sigas" o "una siga" u "otra siga".

La sugerencia de fedorqui, de que es una deformación de "*a la zaga*", no la puedo confirmar pero me parece totalmente plausible.

Comment: Iba a dar la misma respuesta pero nada qué decir. +1

Comment: Gracias @Ustanak, qué bueno que estés de nuevo por aquí.

Answer (score 2):

No hay mucho más que añadir a las otras respuestas. Tan solo que, sorprendentemente, la expresión no viene recogida en el diccionario de americanismos. Sí que se muestran ejemplos en el CORDE (11 casos en 9 documentos, todos de Chile) que ilustran el significado de "tras" explicado por Rodrigo, siendo el que [se muestra a continuación](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=10&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=100417%5C012%5CC000O10042017122701886.1180.1176&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20la%20siga%20de%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto10) el más antiguo (negritas mías):

> *[...] Souper regresó a su campamento sin más novedad que el sacrificio de un tierno potrillo que, muerta la madre peruana en los combates de la víspera, **se puso a la siga de su caravana**; y como relinchara a cada instante, dos soldados se bajaron de sus caballos y después de enlazarlo, de un sablazo lo mataron.*
>
> Benjamín Vicuña Mackenna, "La campaña de Lima", 1881 (Chile).

Y en Ngram encuentro [esta de 1867](https://books.google.es/books?id=DF0sAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA112&dq=%22a%20la%20siga%20de%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtp7bu15nTAhUBPRQKHe8RBpkQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=%22a%20la%20siga%20de%22&f=false):

> *Una mujer del día no es más que un par de colas ambulantes; una cola de caballo en la cabeza y otra de género **a la siga de** los talones.*

Comment: ¡Cierto! Se me olvidó mencionarlo en mi respuesta, pero efectivamente es sorprendente que no conste en el diccionario de americanismos siendo como es tan extendido su uso en Chile.

Comment: La segunda cita, la de las colas, es bastante sorprendente.

Comment: Sí que lo es! Y debo decir, que pierde toda elegancia y ritmo si cambias "a la siga" por cualquiera de sus equivalentes de otras regiones. Fascinante.

Comment: @hlecuanda ¿entiendo que la frase significa que una mujer tiene una cola de hombres siguiéndole los talones? ¿Y "mujer del día" significa algo especial?

Comment: A reserva de una mejor opinión, lo entiendo claramente como una mujer virtuosa, la antípoda de la "mujer de la noche" esa simetría me agrada.